# Return Excel file in Flask

Tags: python, excel, flask, openpyxl

I am building a flask app in python 3. I am trying to write to the output and respond to download. All I am doing is write the sqlite3 db content to a excel file trying to send to the client side for download. everything seems to be working fine till creation of excel file. I am not able to send to the client.

```
@app.route('/download', methods=['GET'])
def export_db():
    values = execute("SELECT * from table",[])
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active

    for item in values.fetchall():
        ws.append(item)
    wb.save('example.xlsx')

    output = make_response(wb)
    output.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=" + 
    "example.xlsx"
    output.headers["Content-type"] = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-
    officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    return output
```

The error message which I received was,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, 
in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, 
in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/home/user/Documents/main.py", 
line 218, in export_db
output = make_response(wb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 
191, in make_response
return current_app.make_response(args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1740, 
in make_response
rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", 
line 911, in force_type
response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", 
line 59, in _run_wsgi_app
return _run_wsgi_app(*args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 
884, in run_wsgi_app
app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'Workbook' object is not callable
```

I have referred to couple of similar questions but none of them seem to help. Any help will be appreciated.

Note:
when I tried adding the file path to the make_response, It takes the file path as a string and returns me a .xlsx file with the file path as content. Any Idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like you are providing incorrect object as input to `make_response`. The supported objects are listed at [Flask.make_response](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.make_response)

Comment: @JRajan I have tried it with a couple of modules like openpyxl, xwlt. all of them return the same error. I want to pass the excel file in supported format. Don't know how to do that?

Comment: did you try the csv module?

Comment: what does ```ws = wb.active``` return?

Comment: wb.active returns the current sheet in excel

Comment: flask is not supposed to guess there is a file in the filesystem (somewhere) with the same name you set in the headers. You make no reference to the file itself after you create it.

Comment: @jsbueno I did add the file path to make_response but it considers that file path as a string and returns me a xlsx file with the file path. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yes - above was a comment on how obvious it is that this could not work, not an answer. The answer is bellow, and you should accept it.

Comment: @jsbueno I didn't accept because that too didn't work

Comment: Have you checked the excel files you are creating are valid? Because  flask.send_file - http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.send_file -  is certainly how one "returns an excel file from flask".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
from flask import send_file
from xlsxwriter import Workbook

@app.route('/download', methods=['GET'])
def export_db():
    values = execute("SELECT * from table",[])
    wb = Workbook('path/to/workbook.xlsx')
    wb.add_worksheet('All Data')

    for item in values.fetchall():
        wb.write(item)
    wb.close()

    return send_file('path/to/workbook.xlsx')
```

Comment: its returning error like Workbook doesn't has a add_worksheet module, are you using openpyxl

Comment: @Arvindkr See my edit. I had assumed you were using `xlsxwriter`.

Comment: Anyway, this answer the part the OP had got wrong, and correctly returns the file as an HTTP response.