# Write large dataframes to excel using Flask and Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, flask, xlsxwriter

I am having a lot of difficulties trying to figure a way to write to a large excel (limited to 1,000,000 rows) file using Pandas/Flask. The error that occurs is a HTTP timeout on the server. After reading on the Flask docs about [Streaming Contents](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/streaming/) this seemed the best way to approach what I am trying to solve. However I am still unsure on how to stream the excel file as it seems that each time I would I have to open and close this file it is yielded.

I first read in my data from a MSSQL database using Pandas in chunks like so:

```
chunks = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM my_table", sql_eng_conn, chunksize=1000)
```

Then I pass the `chunks` return my response using stream with context like so:

```
return Response(stream_with_context(generate_xlsx(chunks, sql_eng_conn)), headers=headers)
```

This calls my function `generate_xlsx` which handles the yielding.

In this first example of `generate_xlsx` the way I approached it was to loop the generator for `chunks` and then when it reaches the threshold value either `top_am` or `excel_limit` then create the excel file and yield the response like so:

```
def generate_xlsx(self, data_chunk, conn_sql_server):
    logger.info('Reading all SQL Server Table')
    try:
        response = ''
        is_complete = False
        total_rows = 0

        for chunk in data_chunk:
            if is_complete:
                break
            total_rows += len(chunk)
            if total_rows == self.top_data or total_rows >= self.limit_rows_xlsx:
                is_complete = True
                output = BytesIO()
                writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
                chunk.to_excel(writer, index=False,
                              sheet_name='Sheet1', encoding='utf-8')
                writer.save()
                output.seek(0)
                response = output.getvalue()
            yield response
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f'Error formatting dataframe to xlsx: {str(e)}')
        raise FormatDataframeToXlsx('Error formatting data to xlsx')
    finally:
        if conn_sql_server is not None:
            conn_sql_server.close()
```

The above works for small sized dataframes such as up to 10000 with a chunk size of 1000. But it seemed to me that for large dataframes it would occur a timeout as nothing was being yielded.

So I attempted to change the function so that I create the writer outside of the loop and yield each chunk on each iteration like so:

```
def generate_large_xlsx(self, data_chunk, conn_sql_server):

    try:

        response = ''
        is_complete = False
        total_rows = 0
        output = BytesIO()
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
        for chunk in data_chunk:
            if is_complete:
                break
            total_rows += len(chunk)
            if total_rows == self.top_am or total_rows >= self.excel_limit:
                is_complete = True
                
            else:
                chunk.to_excel(writer, index=False,
                              sheet_name='Sheet1', encoding='utf-8')
                writer.save()
                output.seek(0)
                response = output.getvalue()
            yield response
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f'Error formatting dataframe to xlsx: {str(e)}')
        raise FormatDataframeToXlsx('Error formatting data to xlsx')
    finally:
        if conn_sql_server is not None:
            conn_sql_server.close()
```

However the error here is that I close a file that has already been closed, resulting in a corrupted file which only returns me the excel of the first chunk (1000 rows of data). I tried to move the `writer.save()` into the condition below (within the function), but this returned an empty file.

```
       if total_rows == self.top_am or total_rows >= self.excel_limit:
           is_complete = True
           writer.save()
```

I also looked around at other similar methods, a few posts on SO ([send_file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47978078/return-excel-file-in-flask/47980237), [send_file 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37426879/excel-export-with-flask-server-and-xlsxwriter), [large excel data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64035310/limit-writing-of-pandas-to-excel-to-1-million-rows-per-sheet)) mentioned using Flask's `send_file` but I am unsure how that would work with streaming contexts.

Is the combination of Pandas/Xlsxwriter a good choice for what I am trying to achieve? Should I consider using something else (for example reading in via Pyodbc). Should I use Flask's `send_file`? Any guidance on this would be great.

Comment: The main issue is that an xlsx file is a zip file and (subject to correction) it can't be streamed until it is fully saved/closed. So you can't stream part of a file until the entire file has been created.

Comment: @jmcnamara Right, ok so in this type of situation, would something asynchronous be a better choice?

Comment: I don't have a solution unfortunately.